# I have two practically identical "for loop" functions, but only one of them works. Why is that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning loops in Python and I'm trying to make a function that takes 2 lists of the same length and returns True if lst1 is the same as lst2 reversed (and false otherwise).

For example: reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]) should return True.

Below there are 2 nearly identical ways of writing this function, I think they should both work correctly but the second one doesn't work even though it is practically identical to the first.

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
    for index in range(len(lst1)):
        if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]:
            return False
    else: return True
#tests
print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]))
#output = True (correct)
print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1]))
#output = False (correct)






def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
    for index in range(len(lst1)):
        if lst1[index] == lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]:
            return True
    else: return False
#tests
print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]))
#output = True (correct but it outputs True even if it should be False)
print(reversed_list([1, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1]))
#output = True (incorrect)
```

The only difference between the two functions is that I changed != to == and swapped True/False accordingly. However, the second function always returns True even if it should be False. I suspect this has something to do with the loop. Please explain why the second function doesn't work properly.

Comment: It is because the second function you return after evaluating the first element from the lists. `return` breaks the loop here, so it should True only if all elements are equal.
BTW, a for loop is not the best way to create this function.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking for, but for your future reference, a more Pythonic way to do what your loops do would be to use `all(a == b for a, b in zip(lst1, reversed(lst2))`. Your first function is directly equivalent to `not any(a != b for a, b in zip(lst1, reversed(lst2))`, while the second function just gets rid of the `not` and changes `!=` to `==`, when it actually needs to switch `any` to `all` as well.

Comment: ^ this. The equivalent of `not any(x)` is `all(not x)` (De Morgan), but an early returning loop is always `any`.

Answer (score 3):

The first one stops early and returns `False` if it finds two entries that don't match; otherwise it returns `True`. The second one stops early and returns `True` as soon as it finds two entries that do match - but your task is to verify all the entries, while this stops after verifying only one. It's basically checking whether there's at least one match, rather than checking whether the whole list is a match.

Comment: Quite right. The OP has run afoul of De Morgan's laws: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the second function is that the function will stop running as soon as it finds a match, rather than check all the values and stop running if finds a pair that doesn't match.

In your case of `[1, 2, 3]` vs `[4, 2, 1]`

When these two lines run:

```
if lst1[index] == lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]:
    return True
```

The second function got to the first pair of items when `index == 0` and saw that `lst[0]` has a value of `1` and that  `lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - 0]` also has a value of `1`. They do match, so the function returns true. It never actually makes it far enough to compare `3` vs `4`

Look into what is called a **fail fast algorithm** if you want to know more about this.